# What is the correct way to simplify a xnor

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I was reading over a resource https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm and I noticed the `xnor` simplification seems to have mixed outputs.

`15a`, `15b`, `15c` are all focusing on `xnor` but only `15b` seems to be correct when I attempt to check.

For reference:

```
15a = (X + Y) • '(X • Y)

15b = 'X'Y + XY

15c =  (X + Y) • ('X + 'Y)
```

The expected truth table for all of them are:

| x | y | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | true |
| 0 | 1 | false |
| 1 | 0 | false |
| 1 | 1 | true |

But only 15b is giving that as the truth table.

Am I solving 15a,15c incorrectly or is the resource incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15b is the definition of XNOR in conjunctive normal form. 15c is the *negation* of XNOR (i.e., XOR) in *disjunctive* normal form. You can derive this using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which state

- `'(XY) == 'X + 'Y`
- `'(X + Y) == 'X'Y`

Using these laws, we can first write 15b

```
'X'Y + XY = '('('X'Y)'(XY))
          = '((X + Y)('X + 'Y))
```

to get the negation of 15c. Using it again, we get the negation of 15a.

```
          = '(X + Y) + '('X + 'Y)
          = '(X + Y) + XY
          = '((X+Y) '(XY))
```

Comment: Would you say the resource I listed is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, because it *is* incorrect.  (At least, 15a and 15c are; they are missing a level of negation.)